# knockout mapping plugin difficulty with observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

just started working with the mapping plug in for knockout. however after reading the documentation I can't figure out why my observableArray is saying it is undefined.

here is the fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/zv39qn64/3/

when I run the fiddle I receive ReferenceError: Books is not defined.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getModelFromServer()
});


var data = {
  LibraryName: "My home library",
  Books: [
    { Id : 1, Title : "Oliver Twist" },
    {Id: 2,  Title: "Moby Dick"}
  ]
};


function getModelFromServer() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    url: '/echo/jsonp/',
    success: function(response) {
    var libraryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);
    ko.applyBindings(libraryViewModel);
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
The library <span data-bind="text: LibraryName"></span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Books">
<li>
    <span data-bind="text: Id"></span> <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The format from the server is not correct, can you show how you send the data from the server?

Comment: it is using jsfiddle's echo functionality. did you try the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getModelFromServer() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(data)},
    url: '/echo/json/',
    success: function(response) {
    var libraryViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);
    ko.applyBindings(libraryViewModel);
    }
  });
}
```

changed only the type to post and the data entry

https://jsfiddle.net/zv39qn64/4/